# global temporary table hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I'm trying to replace a giant IN clause (hundreds of values) with a JOIN for performance reasons, so I created a global temp table (Oracle) hoping that may be a viable alternative:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_USER_GUID (
  user_guid varchar(20)
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
```

When I run my sql manually, it works fine:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO ent.tmp_usr_guid VALUES ('00JD49W7IJ93ZU5MBWBQ')
-- as many INTO statements as I would have IN parameters
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
SELECT u.guid, u.first_name, u.last_name, ...
FROM usr u
JOIN ...
JOIN ...
JOIN tmp_usr_guid tug ON u.guid = tug.usr_guid
```

When I try running it as a native sql statement using Hibernate (5.2.12.FINAL) it throws:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: ';' [INSERT ALL INTO
>   ent.tmp_usr_guid VALUES ('00JD49W7IJ93ZU5MBWBQ') SELECT * FROM DUAL;
>   SELECT u.guid,

Any thoughts on the correct approach to take?

Comment: The method you're calling is supposed to execute a query. You're passing two queries separated by `;`. Don't. If you want to execute 2 queries, call the method twice: once for each query. Note that the methods to execute an inset and to execute a select are often different, though. Read the javadoc.

Comment: I executed two Query operations: the first for the INSERT and the second for the SELECT.  That technique worked fine, however my results were less than spectacular from what I was hoping - the INSERT/SELECT takes twice as long to return results as just the SELECT with IN clause for 1000 values.